# Advice Requested: Keeping list of NuGet Pkgs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

**2 questions in bold below.** Background information is in normal weight.

I'm looking for advice on how to best maintain a list of useful NuGet packages. I am new to .Net development and, as such, only know about a limited number of packages (eg: bower), but I can see how it might be useful to maintain a list of packages that all or most of my applications will employ.

In my case, I expect to only develop responsive web sites/applications (no APIs, expected), so bootstrap and bower are probably a "must", but as I find more and more packages useful, **does anyone have any advice to share on how you remember/keep track of which packages you will reuse in many projects?**

Obviously, I can just keep a list in an excel file, OneNote, Word, whatever, but I am looking for experienced advice, in case there's a better way of which I am unaware.

Secondly, **is there a way to have the same list of NuGet packages automatically installed into new solutions as you create them, without having to go through a list and install manually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does anyone have any advice to share on how you remember/keep track of which packages you will reuse in many projects?

[Package.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/packages-config) should be recommended. The `packages.config` file is used in some project types to maintain the list of packages referenced by the project.

In general, we will not deliberately to keep a list in an excel file or others file to remember/keep track of which packages we will reuse in other projects. When we add a packages to the project by NuGet, NuGet will add a `packages.config` file to the project automatically. There are package ID, version, targetFramework options in that file, so we could use this file to remember/keep track of packages, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
     <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
     <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="Microsoft.Web.Xdt" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" allowedVersions="(8,10]" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="NuGet.Core" version="2.11.1" targetFramework="net46" />

     <!--The following packages will be reused in many projects-->

     <package id="NuGet.Server" version="2.11.2" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="RouteMagic" version="1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  </packages>
```

Note: You can also **add comments** in that file so that you can more easily find the useful info.

> is there a way to have the same list of NuGet packages automatically installed into new solutions as you create them, without having to go through a list and install manually?

We could have the same list of NuGet packages automatically installed into new **project** **not solution**. Because NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0. So we could have the same list for new project by `packages.config` file.

You can **copy the packages list in the packages.config file, add it into the packages.config of the new project**, even you can just copy the `packages.config` file to the new project, then restore the packages and run the command line `Update-Package -reinstall`, after that, the new project will get the same packages list install.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough and well though-out response. This newbie appreciates your help!